# Move a highly referenced cell without having to fix the reference everywhere

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a start date that I reference in about 140 difference cells in all sorts of places on my worksheet (not just one column or row).  This start date is at the bottom of my worksheet and I want to move it to the top without having to change the references everywhere.

How can I do this?

Comment: you can't (unless you use VBA and possibly regex) but what you can do is create a named range and change the references to point to the named range once for all those 140 cells and then if you ever need to move you change change the reference the named range points to.

Comment: using VBA and regex you can iterate over all cells and change for example `A6` ( the cell with the date ) to new cell `A1`

Comment: Surprisingly cutting and pasting it worked and excel did all the work to change the referenced cell on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of an answer:

Just drag it to where you would prefer but beware of functions such as OFFSET and INDIRECT.